# How can I check a boolean expr is literally either TRUE or FALSE?

Tags: boolean, expression, z3

I created the following program:

```
context c;
expr x = c.int_val(1);
expr y = c.int_val(2);
expr b = (x > y).simplify();
std::cout << "b = " << b << "\n";
```

The output said that b = false. But how can I check whether b is the false constant? I want to do something based on b as follows:

```
if (b is false) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: You can refer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17183246/how-to-get-the-model-value-in-sat-problems-using-c-api